# What can I use instead of HTTP_REFERER for reliable tracking?

Tags: php, http-referer

I'm working on a script that will save the refering url for each visitor to a session var and then store it to the db with other data like the google keyword/phrase that brought the visitor to the website as well as if the refering link was a regular google listing (aka organic result) or a paid link (google adwords). 
So far I've come up with this but it doesnt always work. Doing more reading I've found that in several conditions http_referer is blocked or hidden so I'm looking for a better way to get this working.

```
    $session = & JFactory::getSession();
    if (!$session->get('referrer', $origref, 'extref')) //If does not exist
    {
        $origref = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
        $session->set('referrer', $origref, 'extref');

        $url = $session->get('referrer', $origref, 'extref');
        if(!$url && !$url = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : false) {
            $q = 'No referer';
        }

        $parts_url = parse_url($url);
        $query = isset($parts_url['query']) ? $parts_url['query'] : (isset($parts_url['fragment']) ? $parts_url['fragment'] : '');
        if(!$query) {
            $q = 'Not from Google';
        }
        parse_str($query, $parts_query);
        $q = isset($parts_query['q']) ? $parts_query['q'] : isset($parts_query['oq']) ? $parts_query['oq'] : (isset($parts_query['p']) ? $parts_query['p'] : 'could not fetch keyword');

      if(stristr($origref, 'aclk')) { // if referer is a google adwords link as opposed to an organic link
          $type = ', paid link, '.$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
      } else {
          $type = ', organic result, '.$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
      }

    $ginfo = $q.$type;
    $session->set('referrer', $ginfo, 'extref');  
    }

    function search_engine_query_string($url = false) {
        if(!$url && !$url = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : false) {
            return 'No referer';
        }

        $parts_url = parse_url($url);
        $query = isset($parts_url['query']) ? $parts_url['query'] : (isset($parts_url['fragment']) ? $parts_url['fragment'] : '');
        if(!$query) {
            return 'Not from Google';
        }
        parse_str($query, $parts_query);
        return isset($parts_query['q']) ? $parts_query['q'] : (isset($parts_query['p']) ? $parts_query['p'] : '');
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `Referer:` is the closest you will ever get. It is in no way reliable, but it is the most reliable of all 1 available options.

Comment: There's no "reliable" method of tracking people. There's only less failure prone methods

Answer (score 0):

Another typical method is to have a specialized entry url for a tracker identity.  For example:

```
subdomain.mysite.com/tracker?userid=12345&source=adwords
```

When that url is hit, then you know the source is adwords, and you would immediately redirect the user back to the main page with a `header` redirect.  That way, they have no idea about the tracking, and it should be pretty reliable.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but unless you control both ends (that is, the referrer and the referred) I don't think it's possible beyond what you're already doing.

If it's for analysis purposes, you can use [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) and [Google Webmaster Tools](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/).

They both complement each other, and do pretty much want you want to accomplish with your script